# can you run old builds of an app after a new provisioning profile has been made?

Tags: ios, xcode

So the app we are doing we make new builds for clients each week, if the provisioning profile used for the ad-hoc builds (or development ones) is changed, will the old builds we have made for the clients still work on the devices that were provisioned previously?

this has happened and im trying to run an old build on a device i know i have run the build on before (it is our testing device for builds) but now im getting provisioning profile problems when trying to install the old builds, surely the ipa that is signed previously should still work?

Comment: Old build should still work unless its profile is expired or removed from device. What kind of problems are you having?

Comment: hmm the provisioning profile that was used for that build could very well have expired, that is a good point and probably the problem, thanks